# Failure to serialize json by JsonConvert library

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am try to serialize the JSON with the JsonConvert library but i am getting error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'APIConsume.Models.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

The JSON which I am getting is:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Alice","image":"alice.jpg","fromLocation":"New York","toLocation":"Beijing"},{"id":1,"name":"Bob","image":"bob.jpg","fromLocation":"New Jersey","toLocation":"Boston"},{"id":2,"name":"Joe","image":"joe.jpg","fromLocation":"London","toLocation":"Paris"}]
```

My code line giving error is:

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(apiResponse);
```

The RootObject class is generated by http://json2csharp.com/:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string fromLocation { get; set; }
    public string toLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Please help?

Comment: Try `List<RootObject> rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(apiResponse);`

Comment: Looks like an array, try List<RootObject> E: 1 second too slow :')

Comment: @VDWWD List<RootObject> rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(apiResponse); gives compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(apiResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. http://json2csharp.com/ always worked but this time it generated me wrong class.

Comment: It actually is the right class, but you have to be aware that *if* your source is an array of X, *then* you must deserialize into a `List<X>` *or* `X[]` (both will work). json2csharp is just not forcing any choice on you.